# Animate circular progress with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to animate the an arc using UIBezierPath when the user clicks on this custom control.  The bezier path simply snaps forward without any animation.

The reason I override the drawrect is because I want to display this custom control in interface builder.  Is there a good approach for displaying the circular progress in interface builder and have the progress animate?

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

@IBDesignable class CircleControl:UIControl {
    @IBInspectable var progressTotal:CGFloat = 100

    @IBInspectable var progressCounter:CGFloat = 20
    {
    willSet(newProgressCounter) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.duration = 0.5;
        animation.toValue = newProgressCounter;
        animation.delegate = self;
        layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "strokeEnd")
    }

    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let center = CGPointMake(bounds.size.width / 2, bounds.size.height / 2)
        let radius = bounds.size.width / 2;
        let pi = CGFloat(M_PI)
        let sliceAngle:CGFloat = (2 * pi) / progressTotal

        let progressAngle:CGFloat = sliceAngle * progressCounter
        let startAngle:CGFloat = CGFloat(-M_PI_2) + sliceAngle
        let endAngle:CGFloat = startAngle + progressAngle;

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.addArcWithCenter(center, radius: radius - 5, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        path.lineWidth = 5
        path.stroke()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        println("touch")

        self.progressCounter = 80
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        self.progressCounter = 20
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to animate inside IB?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot animate inside of IB.  You might be able to do this in a playground but IB is for layout only - it does not do animations.  You must preview in the simulator or playgrounds.